# Parallel write to Excel file c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, openxml, export-to-excel, epplus

From some time I am struggling with exporting data from db (stored procedures) to excel files. As I am working with loads of data (around 500k rows per sheet, business requirement unfortunately) I was wondering whether there is the possibility to execute parallel writes to a single worksheet. I am using EPPlus and OpenXML for writing to the files. As I was reading through the web, I was able to understand that the User Defined Functions can be executed in parallel, but I didn't found anything for parallel writing. Any help/advice/hint/etc. will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge, no. You can program it, but it's a hell

If You want to export to Excel fastly I think that you have two ways.

1. CVS (fields separated by semicolon).
2. Use Excel with ADO. You can insert registers with Sql Sentences.

More info:

[MSDN: How To Transfer Data from ADO Data Source to Excel with ADO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295646)

[StackOverflow: ado in excel, inserting records into access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919696/ado-in-excel-inserting-records-into-access-database)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you'll not be able to write to a single file in parallel. A better way is to create separate files (you can write to them in parallel :)) and finally merge the sheets to get a single document. you can do that using OpenXML. Here is an example - http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2011/01/24/open-xml-sdk-merging-documents.aspx

Well, parallel would be ambiguous, I'm thinking of multi-threading which is concurrent.

Comment: Unfortunately PowerTools works only with .docx but not with .xlsx